# How To Remove SharedPreferences Item From An Isolate In Flutter

Tags: android, multithreading, flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I am using [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) plugin and I am trying to remove an item from `SharedPreferences` in an isolate. But it doesn't seem to work. The item still exists on the main thread when i try to access it.
Below is my code to remove the item in the isolate:

```
SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool x = await pref.remove('image_post_data');
if (x == true) print('removed image_post_data'); // This is printed out
```

But when I try to access `image_post_data` on the main thread, I still get the value instead of getting a null. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reload Your SharedPreferences instance after updating it in your isolate and before using it in your main thread. By calling

```
pref.reload()
```

Comment: THANK YOU. I was getting a dang headache cause of this.